# Batch file to find all images and copy to a folder

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

Not even sure if this is possible, but I'd figured i'd give it a try.

So here's my problem. I need to search multiple big hard drives (1TB and bigger) for all images and move them to one folder. My issue i'm having is no matter what language I try to write this in I can't seem to figure out a answer. I either want it to be vbs or bat related not using the robocopy command. Some of my drives are all different formats such as fat32 and ntfs. My issue with a few scripts I tried with the batch file was my file names are too long. So the main functions I need it to do is find the images, copy them, rename them with a _001 _002 if they exist, count how many files are moved, and then finally delete them or move them to a seperate folder for deleting ( a little more safe in my eyes ). Any help would be appreciated because I am totally stumped on this.

Here is one script that I was working on but just stopped on. The problem with this is it copied the files, but did not keep the extension for some reason. This was one I found online and modified the code on a little. I'm very familiar with code, but for some reason can't seem to figure this out.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set TESTFOLDER=allpictures
md "%TESTFOLDER%"


set /a counter=0
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('DIR /S /B /A-D C:\Users\user1\Desktop\*.jpg') DO FOR /F "tokens=*" %%j IN ('DIR /B "%%i"') DO IF EXIST ".\%TESTFOLDER%\%%j" (
        set /a counter=!counter!+1
        echo folder: %TESTFOLDER%
        copy "%%i" ".\%TESTFOLDER%\%%j_!counter!"
    ) ELSE copy /B "%%i" ".\%TESTFOLDER%\%%j"
:eof
```

**Edit:** VBScript Code Below

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

testfolder = ".\allpictures"
'fso.CreateFolder(testfolder)

CopyFiles fso.GetFolder("E:\")

Sub CopyFiles(fldr)
  For Each f In fldr.Files
    basename  = fso.GetBaseName(f)
    extension = fso.GetExtensionName(f)
    If LCase(extension) = "jpg" Then
      dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, f.Name)
      count = 0
      Do While fso.FileExists(dest)
        count = count + 1
        dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, basename & "_" & count & "." _
          & extension)
      Loop
      f.Copy dest
    End If
  Next

  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    CopyFiles sf
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why not use Perl? Do we know all the extensions for the files(.jpg, .gif, etc)?

Comment: Never really thought of using perl to be honest. Would this be a better option for me? As for the file extensions yes I'm searching for all jpg extensions. Eventually I want to use this for a backup to help organize my files is my main goal to help me keep my files organized. For example if I wanted to search for mov files at a later date.

Comment: I added to the original question the code i was working on.

Comment: For all my brute file operations, I use Perl and it works great and is very simple. Saying it would be "better" for you would be subjective ;). It is a marvelous workhorse and is ideal for putting together quick and easy file operations. For windows, you can download [Strawberry](http://strawberryperl.com/) and it will run great.

Answer (score 3):

**What you shouldn't do**: Don't let you be hoodwinked into

1. producing code before you have understood the problem in full and have a detailed plan about the procedure. (Nobody likes "give me a program to solve my problem" type of questions, and sometimes a code snippet may clarify a problem, but asking people to try what they admittedly can't do is poor didactic.)
2. start with a new language to solve the problem at hand (plan or no plan). (If you are stuck writing a love letter in your native language, what are the chances to get it right with a grammar and a vocabulary of a foreign one?)

**What you should do**:

1. Think about your problem with a focus on the ultimate aim: organizing your images (if I understand your comment correctly). How would that look like? Certainly not one folder with thousands of files with mangled names. I would strive to end with a folder tree containing .jpgs with decent names, or a database with suitable meta-info about my pictures (videos?) and pathes to their storage, or even an upload to some cloud storage. From that ultimate aim work backwards: what do you need in the previous step.
2. I assume, the very first step is a list of all your .jpgs. What is - given your knowledge, skills, and tools - the easiest way to get this list? Probably some variation of `dir /s [/b] c:\*.jpg > jpglist.txt`. For many drives or other extensions that come up later, you can combine many such lines in one .cmd file (`>/>>`). This list and a text editor or a bit of filtering and a spreadsheet can give you valuable information about your task: How many files? Sum of all sizes? Duplicate files names? Possible classifications?
3. Buy a new external drive (you know the size by now). That way you can postpone the deleting to the step after you presented your beautifully organized collection to the astonished audience. [And this last task would be trivial: Just feed your jpglist.txt thru a "delete" filter script or use the search and replace facility of your text editor to put `"del /Q "` at the beginning of the lines.]
4. Depending on your needs and skills you can transform the basic jpglist.txt into new .csv files with pertinent information, that can be manually scanned/checked via a spreadsheet program and/or programmatically use to generate file or folder names (appending numbers should be the last fallback). If you'd like some JPG metadata and don't know how, you can ask here (and then even show the code you used to get sizes or dates for those files).
5. Make each step repeatable and as non-destructive as possible (e.g. don't move or delete files you can't recreate with one command before you are all done). Use the techniques/tools you know; that definitely rules out "code found on the internet"); if you want to learn something new/more interesting then do it in a toy project.

Answer (score 1):

It's overkill to install a new script interpreter for something that can easily be handled by the script interpreters shipped with the operating system.

The reason why your script doesn't maintain the extension is because you append the content of the counter variable at the end of the file name, so `foo.jpg` becomes `foo.jpg1` for a counter value of 1. You have to work with modifiers to avoid that: `%%~nj` gives you just the name of the file (without path and extension), `%%~xj` just the extension. Also, you probably don't want a single counter for all files, but one counter per duplicate file name.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set TESTFOLDER=allpictures
md "%TESTFOLDER%"

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d C:\Users\user1\Desktop\*.jpg') do (
  call :copyfile "%%~i"
)

goto :eof

:copyfile
set fname=%~nx1
set counter=0

if not exist ".\%dest%\!fname!" goto docopy

:recheck
if exist ".\%dest%\%~n1_!counter!%~x1" (
  set /a counter+=1
  goto recheck
)
set fname=%~n1_!counter!%~x1

:docopy
copy "%~1" ".\%dest%\!fname!"

goto :eof

endlocal
```

In VBScript you could do something like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

testfolder = ".\allpictures"
fso.CreateFolder(testfolder)

CopyFiles fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\user1\Desktop")

Sub CopyFiles(fldr)
  For Each f In fldr.Files
    basename  = fso.GetBaseName(f)
    extension = fso.GetExtensionName(f)
    If LCase(extension) = "jpg" Then
      dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, f.Name)
      count = 0
      Do While fso.FileExists(dest)
        count = count + 1
        dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, basename & "_" & count & "." _
          & extension)
      Loop
      f.Copy dest
    End If
  Next

  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    CopyFiles sf
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This actually worked out really nicely, but now I have another problem. I decided to use vbscript for this since the batch file still comes up file names are too long. Plus I think the vb works a little better. My problem now is instead of using c:\users\etc... I need to pull all images from the E: Drive and all subfolders, but i'm having a issue with the code. I know the code is programmed to grab foldres and its something very minor I need to change to get this to work, but I don't know VB Script good enough to figure it out. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

testfolder = ".\allpictures"
'fso.CreateFolder(testfolder)

CopyFiles fso.GetFolder("E:\")

Sub CopyFiles(fldr)
  For Each f In fldr.Folder.Files
    basename  = fso.GetBaseName(f)
    extension = fso.GetExtensionName(f)
    If LCase(extension) = "jpg" Then
      dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, f.Name)
      count = 0
      Do While fso.FileExists(dest)
        count = count + 1
        dest  = fso.BuildPath(testfolder, basename & "_" & count & "." _
          & extension)
      Loop
      f.Copy dest
    End If
  Next

Comment: For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    CopyFiles sf
  Next
End Sub

Comment: @dkrider471: Simply replacing `"C:\Users\user1\Desktop"` with `"E:\"` should do just fine. Does this not work for you? If so: how? What result do you get, what result do you expect, and how does one differ from the other?

Comment: Its saying that Line: 9 char 3 Path not found and thats what I thought to was just change it to E:\ and it would work, but its not for some odd reason. I attached exactly how its typed on my very first post just to show exactly how I typed it.

Comment: Which line exactly is line 9 in your code? According to your your updated question it should be `For Each f In fldr.Files`. Is that correct? Do names of files on drive E: have special characters in them?

Comment: Yes that is the line and Yes one of them has " Program files (x86) folder " I didnt even think of that until you just said that.

Answer (score -2):

If utilizing perl, you could glob all of the files in a given directory an put them in an array. `my @Files = glob '<directory>\*.jpg';`

The go through each file with a loop  `foreach $file (@Files){ ... }`

Each .jpg would be referred to as `$file` in the loop. You can get the file name by 
   `my ($originalfilename) = $file;` and add any extension you want then copy/move it to any other directory you want. Also, in that loop, you can increment your counter loop or just get the scalar value of the array.

There is a ton of stuff on [HERE](http://perldoc.perl.org/) for perl documentation and tutorials all over the internet. It is worth learning some basic perl if file manipulation is going to be common place.

Comment: -1 for asking a person to learn a new prgramming language to solve a problem at hand.

Comment: @bwtrent: What would you think if I propose a Batch solution for a perl asked question arguing certain advantages of Batch over perl? In my opinion, Batch file solutions have _NOT_ less value or merit than any other language solutions...

Comment: I would think you were trying to help. By providing concepts of another language, it may help spur me in the right direction. This was my mistake and I do apologize to the community. Lesson learned. Shan't happen again. Thank you to @Ekkehard.Horner for answering the question more informatively and helpfully.